# How to write content type in cakephp?

Tags: php, http, cakephp, header, content-type

How can i write ["Content-Type"] = "text/xml" in cakephp and in which file i have to include that one.

Please Help.

Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to set a header?

Comment: ya i am trying to set the Header for my page

Answer (score 5):

The Cake way is to use [RequestHandlerComponent::respondAs](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1295/Responding-To-Requests), like
`$this->RequestHandler->respondAs('xml')`, somewhere in the controller. This may even happen automatically if your app [is set up appropriately](http://book.cakephp.org/complete/1238/REST).

The PHP way is to issue `header('Content-Type: text/xml')` anywhere before any output (usually somewhere in the controller).

Comment: Updated doc link: https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/request-handling.html