# SoapServer sends text/html header instead of text/xml

Tags: php, soapserver

My soap server sends Content-Type: text/html in the response header. I need Content-type: text/xml.

```
public function index()
{
    $this->layout = 'soap';
    ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
    $this->server = new SoapServer('wsdl/tur.wsdl', array(
            'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2, 
    ));
    $this->server->setObject($this);
    $this->server->handle();
}
```

Here is server's response:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 19 Mar 2012 12:17:10 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.6-13ubuntu3.6
Set-Cookie: CAKEPHP=msmid2fijgrj1efjs0otl8qfj1; expires=Mon, 19-Mar-2012 16:17:10 GMT; path=/
P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 877
Content-Type: **text/html**; charset=UTF-8

I've tried to call header() with text/xml conent type

```
public function index()
{
    $this->layout = 'soap';
    ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

    header("Content-Type: text/xml");

    $this->server = new SoapServer('wsdl/tur.wsdl', array(
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2, 
    ));
    $this->server->setObject($this);
    $this->server->handle();
}
```

before and after constructing SoapServer, but no result.

Comment: Never worked with this but in documenation there is `SoapServer::addSoapHeader` did you try that to override Content-Type?

Comment: According to a comment on the doc for `handle`, "...`SoapServer::handle();` method sends additional HTTP headers to the browser. One of them is 'Content-Type: application/soap+xml'." Not really an answer, but may provide some insight.

Answer (score 1):

(Answered in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> Solved, it was a сakephp feature. Thanks to [How to write content type in cakephp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341042/how-to-write-content-type-in-cakephp)
>
> ```
> public function index()
> {
>     $this->layout = 'soap';
>     ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
>     $this->server = new SoapServer('wsdl/tur.wsdl', array(
>         'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
>     ));
>     $this->server->setObject($this);
>     $this->server->handle();
>
>     $this->RequestHandler->respondAs('text/xml');
> }
> ```